# Retrieve data from database in an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Is there any php function that will let me retrieve data from mysql in numeric array. If there's no function for that, how can I do it?

I am trying to retrieve a list of email from a database, but I need to retrieve those emails in a numeric array. I tried this but it's not working.

```
    $a=mysql_connect("X","X","X");
    mysql_select_db("X",$a);
    function num(){
     $email=mysql_query("select email from X");
     while($re=mysql_fetch_array($email)){
      print $re[0];
      print "<br>";
     }
    }
    num();
```

Comment: I tried this to put these emails in a numeric array but it won't work $fr=explode("<br>",num());

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line:

```
while($re=mysql_fetch_array($email)){
```

With this one:

```
while($re=mysql_fetch_array($email, MYSQL_NUM)){
```

Comment: When I try to print a specific email I get this error: undefined offset: 8 (If I try "print $re[8]";)

Comment: Of course, that's because $re is **one** row, so you are printing the 8th column of that row

Answer (score 1):

mysql_fetch_array returns both numerical and associative indexes. Jeroen is correct, in that you can set a second parameter to define what kind of indexing you would like, but consider using this for numerical indexing:

```
while($re=mysql_fetch_row($email)){
```

And this for associative indexing:

```
while($re=mysql_fetch_assoc($email)){
```

As for your function, you can do something like this:

```
$a=mysql_connect("X","X","X");
mysql_select_db("X",$a);
$emails = num("select email from X");
function num($query){
    $email=mysql_query($query);
    $results = array();
    while($re=mysql_fetch_assoc($email)){
        $results[] = $re;
    }
    return $results;
}
print $emails[8]['email'];
```

You should also stop using the mysql_* functions, and consider switching to something like PDO.

Answer (score 0):

```
function num(){
 $email=mysql_query("select email from X");
 $result = array();
 while($re=mysql_fetch_array($email)){
  $result[] = $re[0];
 }
 return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For an array with numerical keys:

```
mysql_fetch_row()
```